# Update_method not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following problem with the update method.

Here's my code:

```
def edit
  @work_package = WorkPackage.find(params[:package])
  unless current_user.admin? || own_project?(@project)
  flash[:danger] = I18n.t('messages.errors.no_admin_rights_for_site')
  redirect_to projects_path
  return
 end
end

def update
   @work_package = WorkPackage.find(params[:id])
    if @work_package.update_attributes(filter_update_work_package_params) 
    flash[:success] = updated_success_message(I18n.t('objects.work_package'))
    redirect_to project_path(@work_package.project_id)
else
  @object = @work_package
  render 'edit' 
 end
end
```

And this my work_package params

```
private

def filter_work_package_params
  params.require(:work_package).permit(:name, :parent_id, :project_id, :started_on, :finished_on)
end

def filter_update_work_package_params
   params.permit(:package_id, :project_id, :team_id, :person_month, :started_on, :finished_on)
end
```

When I click on submit, nothing happened

Here is the console-log:

```
Started PATCH "/work_packages/33" for ::1 at 2015-11-06 09:14:49 +0100
Processing by WorkPackagesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R6k9B20nfUj4BSRDcA9+D+V73ihR9l9AzjFtBIoDYFGhxCkO+WsqOQzWhG7NCprxcQ3juJahH46ftHB94b3YNg==", "work_package"=>{"name"=>"Faraz", "parent_id"=>"", "project_id"=>"6", "started_on"=>"05.11.2015", "finished_on"=>"12.12.2015"}, "commit"=>"Absenden", "id"=>"33"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
WorkPackage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "work_packages".* FROM "work_packages" WHERE "work_packages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 33]]
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, work_package, commit, id
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/6
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try using the `filter_work_package_params` for the `update` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is the error:

> Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, **work_package**, commit, id

---

You'll need to do this:

```
def filter_update_work_package_params
   params.require(:work_package).permit(:package_id, :project_id, :team_id, :person_month, :started_on, :finished_on)
end
```

This will permit the unpermitted `work_package` parameter, and should resolve your issue.

--

You can also fix some of your other code too:

```
def edit
  @work_package = WorkPackage.find(params[:package])
  redirect_to projects_path, danger: I18n.t('messages.errors.no_admin_rights_for_site') if !current_user.admin? || !own_project?(@project)
end

def update
   @work_package = WorkPackage.find(params[:id])
   if @work_package.update filter_update_work_package_params 
     redirect_to project_path(@work_package.project_id), success: updated_success_message(I18n.t('objects.work_package'))
   else
     @object = @work_package
     render 'edit' 
   end
end
```

Comment: Why the OP needs to change the `filter_update_work_package_params` like this if he has `filter_work_package_params` which do the same

Comment: Because he's calling `filter_update_work_package_params` in his code. I don't know his attributes so perhaps the two are different

Comment: I believe he is calling the wrong method,see in `params` hash the `name` is present and the `filter_work_package_params` only has `name` in it.

Comment: `ActionController::ParameterMissing at /work_packages/33
param is missing or the value is empty: work_package`

Comment: `Request parameters
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"FgxyekAOoChXsjfgGJ4sd2HRlwWkBiKBEMlcTcibs/nwYWZz1EL3WaNhl82lm8iJ9aeqlWNRYk9BTEE0oyULng==", "team_id"=>"2", "person_month"=>"0", "project_id"=>"6", "commit"=>"save", "controller"=>"work_packages", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"33"}`

Comment: These are totally different than the params you originally posted - are your sure your `edit` form is still as it was?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `filter_update_work_package_params`:

```
def filter_update_work_package_params
  params.require(:work_package).permit(:package_id, :project_id, :team_id, :person_month, :started_on, :finished_on)
end
```

Comment: Why the OP needs to change the `filter_update_work_package_params` like this if he has `filter_work_package_params` which do the same.

Comment: Notice that `filter_update_work_package_params` have different attributes. I am thinking that he needs the other attributes that not included to `filter_work_package_params`.

Comment: I believe he is calling the wrong method,see in `params` hash the `name` is present and the `filter_work_package_params` only has name in it.